# producer-consumer pattern using java and spring

Tags: java, spring, producer-consumer

I need to resolve a problem using producer-consumer pattern using Java and Spring framework. The problem is that I am new in Spring framework (I have no idea) so could anyone guide me in the right direction about how to do this using Spring? Some book or internet site where I can find an example step by step about implementing producer-consumer pattern with Spring?

Answer (score 5):

You have two options:

- synchronous using `ApplicationEventPublisher` ([more](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2))
- asynchronous using Spring Reactor ([more](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-reactor/))

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will give it a try.